# Moments of Elementary symmetric functions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, symmetric-functions

For the elementary symmetric function 
$$e_k(\mathbf{x}) =  \sum_{\substack{\mathbf{y} : y_j \in {0,1},\\\sum_j y_j = k}} \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{y_j}$$

for a fixed $\mathbf{x}$ where all elements are positive if I plot the $e_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ where $n$ is length of $\mathbf{x}$ I see these beautiful unimodal log-concave shaped curves:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is any work related to approximating this curve or perhaps calculating moments

Comment: It’s asymptotically normal; you can see this from a mild generalization of the central limit theorem, applied to independent but not identically distributed coin flips.

Comment: what is the mean and variance for such a generalized binomial?

Comment: Ah yes that helped a lot thanks!